# User-Agent IOs application version check in asp.net webapi 2

Tags: c#, ios, api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem here. I Have ASP.NET WebApi2 on my server, and Ios app that works with it. Now I should implement application version check on server, for example, if user has old application version, API will send related error. The current version will be stored in web.config. The problem is that I need to implement this check as high as possible in API workflow pipeline. If you have any ideas or recommendations I would be very grateful if you could share them with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find a solution. I created my own DelegatingHandler

```
public class VersionObsessedHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Headers.UserAgent.Any())
        {
            var product = request.Headers.UserAgent.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Product.Name == "APPLICATION").Product;

            if (product != null && request.Headers.UserAgent.Any(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Comment) && s.Comment.ToLower().Contains("ios")) && !product.Version.Equals(Constants.IOS_APP_VERSION))
                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { message = "Please update your application" });
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken); ;
    }
}
```

And added it to configuration

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new VersionObsessedHandler());
```